# Validation before saving Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

I would like to carry out a validation before saving by determining if a User has filled in a particular field, the Payment amount field below and chosen status = "Closed" before submitting the form. If he does one without the other then the form should not save

Edit page

```
<%= simple_form_for @invoice, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @invoice %>

<%= f.association :customer, disabled: @invoice.persisted? %>
<%= f.input :due_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" }, disabled:  @invoice.persisted? %>
<%= f.input :invoice_date, as: :string, input_html: { class: "datepicker" }, disabled: @invoice.persisted? %>
<%= f.input :payment_method, as: :select, :collection => [['Cash','Cash'],['Cheque','Cheque'],['In-House transfer','In-House transfer'],['Account Ledger','Account ledger']], :selected => ['Cash','Cash'] %>
<%= f.input :reference_no, :label => 'Payment Reference No', as: :string %>
<%= f.input :amount, as: :string %>
<%= f.input :payment_date, as: :string, input_html: {class: "datepicker"} %>
<%= f.input :status, as: :select, collection: Invoice::VALID_STATUS %>
```

VALID_STATUS = [ 'Draft', 'Open', 'Closed', 'Void' ] in Invoice.rb

I would like that if the user changes the Status to Closed he should have entered an amount in the form. A user should not be able to change status to closed without entering an amount

Comment: Do you want to do this server side, after the form is posted, or client side, before posting the form? (Really, the right answer is both, but what is your question?)

Comment: Is jQuery ok or does it have to be raw javascript? Are you in control of the javascript libraries/plugins that you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the model (`app/models/invoice_model.rb`) put

```
validate :close_must_have_amount
```

Then define it (same file)

```
def close_must_have_amount
  :status == 'closed' && :amount # May need to tweak this
end
```

To have the model level validations applied client side you can use
https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/

Comment: I have tried to use your method and get the error "uninitialized constant Invoice::False" I changed amount not nil to !amount.nil?

Comment: Actually I think you can just use amount (updated the answer) as this is active record and the attribute will exist.

Answer (score 3):

1) Javascript Form Validation is generally done by names.

```
 function ValidateForm(){
     var form = document.forms['myForm'];
     if ((form['status'].value == "Closed") && !(form['amount'].value)){
         alert("You gave a 'Closed' status value, but did not provide an amount, please rectify this problem!");
         return(false);
     } else {
        return(true);
     }
 }
```

And then:

```
         <%= simple_form_for @invoice, :onsubmit => "ValidateForm();", :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :name => 'myForm' } do |f| %>
         <%= f.input :amount, :html => { :name => 'amount'}, as: :string %>
         <%= f.input :status, as: :select, :html => { :name => 'status'}, collection: Invoice::VALID_STATUS %>
```

A brief walkthrough `onSubmit` triggers when a form is submitted, but before it is actually posted to the server.

A javascrtipt function that is trigered by an event and terminates with `return(false);` will immediately terminate the event, while `return(true);` (or pretty much anything else really) makes the event continue as planned.

Finally, be aware that relying exclusively on client side validation is a terrible idea, as a determined user could do something like:

1) Make a perfectly legitimate submission with firebug open and inspect the headers etc.
2) Craft their own HTTP request containing bogus/bad data.
3) Submit it through any one of the myriad HTTP tools.

Clientside Validation is a "nice to have".
Serverside Validation is a "must have".

Comment: +Abraham P, thanks for the response. This is great. How would I do it then on the Server side the issues raised above

Comment: @zurik Solution given by Michael Durrant is server side validation

Comment: added info about gem that would use model level validation for client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in client side:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#status').change(function(){
          if($(this).val() == "Closed" && ($('#amount').val() == null || $('#amount') == "")){
            alert("Amount must be needed when status is closed")
          }
        });
     });
</script>
```